# Using Pattern.MULTILINE in java regex

Tags: java, regex

From this [API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#MULTILINE):

> **MULTILINE**
>
> `public static final int MULTILINE`
>
> Enables multiline mode.  In multiline mode the expressions `^` and `$` match just after or just before, respectively, a line terminator or the end of the input sequence. By default these expressions only match at the beginning and the end of the entire input sequence.
>
> Multiline mode can also be enabled via the embedded flag expression `(?m)`.

Can anybody make a real life code example of the difference of having a Pattern created with `Pattern.MULTILINE` and with standard settings?

The boundary matcher `^` as default should match the beginning of the line and `$` the end of the line as [this](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/bounds.html) tutorial explaines.

What does it change by using the `Pattern.MULTILINE`?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Contrived example: you want to match a specific import line in a Java source file, say:

```
import foo.bar.Baz;
```

In order to match that line anywhere in the input, which is multiline, the easier solution is to use `Pattern.MULTILINE` along with this regex:

```
^\s*import\s+foo\.bar\.Baz\s*;\s*$
```

Here the `^` will match right after a newline and the `$` right before. Which is desirable in such a situation.

And:

> The boundary matcher ^ as default should match the beginning of the line and $ the end of the line as this tutorial explaines.

this is untrue. By default, `^` matches the beginning of the *input*, and `$` matches the end of the input.

Illustration:

```
public static void main(final String... args)
{
    final Pattern p1 = Pattern.compile("^dog$");
    final Pattern p2 = Pattern.compile("^dog$", Pattern.MULTILINE);

    final String input = "cat\ndog\nTasmanian devil";

    System.out.println(p1.matcher(input).find());
    System.out.println(p2.matcher(input).find());
}
```

This outputs:

```
false
true
```

Comment: So the oracle tutorial I linked (in the latter bit you quoted) is wrong?

Comment: What is the difference between \A and ^ then?

Comment: The difference is that `\A` will always match the beginning of input, even with `Pattern.MULTILINE`. In the second regex above, if you replace `^` by `\A`, then the second printout will be `false`.